# Landscape-only app still autorotates to portrait in iOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, landscape

After updating to iOS7, my app shows autorotation.
I want it to be a landscape-only app and, accordingly, I set up everything as follows:
In iOS6 was fine.

[image]

In .plist file:

[image]

In my `MainWindow` controller

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

The `AppDelegate.m` call it as:

```
 MainViewController* mainViewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
    // Create the navigation controller
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                             initWithRootViewController:mainViewController];


    [navController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
    [[self window] setRootViewController:navController];
```

But still the app autorotate in portrait mode when I rotate the device.
In iOS 6 I had not such behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this,

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Apparently, I did not put the supportedInterfaceOrientation method inside the AppDelegate