# iOS7 UIImagePickerController TypeSavedPhotosAlbum only Portrait upside up

Tags: ios7, orientation, uiimagepickercontroller

Hi I'm developing an universal app which is only portrait.

All view controllers the orientation works great, but in the UIImagePickerController type TypeSavedPhotosAlbum is always showed in Portrait upside up (the modal view always comes from the top, and it's not the same orientation as the rest of the app). In fact in the TypeCamera, when the camera appears, you can see how the view turn around.

I've used the default code from apple tutorial:

```
- (BOOL) startCameraControllerFromViewController: (UIViewController*) controller
                                        type:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)typeCamera
                               usingDelegate: (id <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
                                               UINavigationControllerDelegate>) delegate {

if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
      UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == NO)
    || (delegate == nil)
    || (controller == nil))
    return NO;

UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
cameraUI.sourceType = typeCamera;
cameraUI.allowsEditing = YES;


cameraUI.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeImage, nil];
cameraUI.delegate = delegate;

[self.navigationController presentViewController:cameraUI animated:YES completion:NULL];
return YES;
}
```

And this is my app orientation configuration.

[image: Deplyment Info]

Any idea? I has try to add this solution:

[Landscape-only app still autorotates to portrait in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19785333/landscape-only-app-still-autorotates-to-portrait-in-ios7)

But with (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait); and with (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait).

I has tried to change the orientation from plist, but I don't know what I can do.

Thanks!!!!!!

UPDATE:

I've just tried with

```
  - (NSUInteger)navigationControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
  {
     return  (UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
  }
  - (UIInterfaceOrientation)navigationControllerPreferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
  {
    return  (UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
  }
```

And I keep the problem :S.

Thanks!